# Android DatePicker to use Spinner in.net Maui(not calendar)

Tags: maui

I want to customize my DatePicker in .Net Maui to use the Spinner mode on Android(possible modes in android) and not the calendar mode.

1. Created a styles.xml file in the [Platforms/Android/Resources/values] folder.

2.And added content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  
  <style name="Maui.SplashTheme" parent ="MainTheme.Base">
      <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/style_date_picker</item>
  </style>

  <style name="style_date_picker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
    <item name="android:spinnersShown">true</item>
  </style>
 
</resources>
```

3. And the content of MainActivity is

```
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
    }
```

Even if I do this, it's only displayed in calendar mode, what's wrong?

Comment: `Maui.SplashTheme` is already being used by Maui, shouldn't you use some other name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can check [the source code about the android default style on the github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Platform/Android/Resources/values/styles.xml). And I copy all the code into the custom **Platforms/Android/Resources/values/styles.xml**, and then I also add your code into it.

I added `<item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>` in the **Maui.SplashTheme**, but it didn't work. But if I added the `<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/style_date_picker</item>` in the **Maui.SplashTheme**. It will work.

In addition, I also try to use the custom handler to do that:

Create the custom handler in the \Platforms\Android:

```
public class MyDatePickerHandler : DatePickerHandler
 {
     protected override DatePickerDialog CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
     {
         var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context!,global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeHoloLightDialog, (o, e) =>
         {
             if (VirtualView != null)
             {
                 VirtualView.Date = e.Date;
             }
         }, year, month, day);
         return dialog;
     }
 
 }
```

And use the handler in the mauiprogram.cs:

```
 .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                })
                .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
#if ANDROID
                   handlers.AddHandler(typeof(DatePicker), typeof(Platforms.Android.MyDatePickerHandler));
#endif
                });
```

And the result image:

[image]

The two way both make the datepicker show as spinner.

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you.